# Is a <p> element for small amounts of text semantically correct

Tags: html, semantics

I've always wondered if `<p>` elements are semantically correct for small amounts of text.

When I think of a paragraph I actually visualize a large chunk of text.

In the example below I have used a `<p>` element to display the password strength of the user input password in a sign up form.

```
<div class="inputs">
    <div class="field">
        <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First" />
        <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input id="email-confirm" type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" />
        <p>Password strength: Weak</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `p` for paragraphs... use `span`

Comment: `<p>` for paragraph, for small text better use `<span>` element

Comment: Note: this question does not seem to be entirely off-topic, however, I recommend [Pro Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo?sort=votes&pageSize=15) for future similar questions.

Comment: The word "tag" is not semantically correct.

Comment: HTML specifications are vague and obscure about the “meaning” of the `p` element. Besides, being a paragraph is really a matter of structure, not meaning; meaning (i.e., semantics) is something related to what the actual content says. So this is very much a matter of opinions.

Comment: `aria-describedby` would probably be appropriate here, indicating the password input is described by the text within the <p> tag

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 spec says that

> A paragraph is typically a run of phrasing content that forms a block
>   of text with one or more sentences that discuss a particular topic, as
>   in typography, but can also be used for more general thematic
>   grouping. For instance, an address is also a paragraph, as is a part
>   of a form, a byline, or a stanza in a poem.

And also

> Note: While paragraphs are usually represented in visual media by
>   blocks of text that are physically separated from adjacent blocks
>   through blank lines, a style sheet or user agent would be equally
>   justified in presenting paragraph breaks in a different manner, for
>   instance using inline pilcrows (¶).

The only conclusion that can be drawn from the above is that this is not a semantically correct use of `<p>` because *it is not grouping anything together*.

It would be more appropriate to use a semantically neutral `<span>` in this situation or perhaps something more specific such as a `<label>`.

On the other hand, the `<div class="field">` elements *are* being used to group controls and visually separate adjacent groups so replacing `<div>` with `<p>` would be semantically appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There are varying opinions, but I always use `<p>` for a block of text content that is all relative to each other.  This is generally a paragraph, but there is nothing saying that it can't be a short paragraph.  If you have a couple sentences that go together, using the paragraph tag is fine.

In your example of `<p>Password strength: Weak</p>`, I think a `<label>` or `<dd>` is more appropriate, since you are associating that data with the `<input>` field.

Comment: If you use a `dd` here, you'd be abusing a list. An input and a remark about password strength do not make up a list!

Comment: @MrLister I don't necessarily disagree, but I think it's better than `<p>`.